# How to configure Guice to require explicit bindings for the whole application (for all modules)

Tags: guice

In order to to use "explicit" bindings with Guice I can call `binder().requireExplicitBindings()` in my module implementations, e.g.

```
public class MyExampleModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.configure();
        binder().requireExplicitBindings();
        ...
    }
}
```

Regarding the Guice API, it looks for me like I need to do that in **all** my module implementations of my application.

Isn't there a way to configure this **at one place** for the whole application?

I'm using Guice 4.2.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binder configuration options like `requireExplicitBindings()` are global for everywhere that `Binder` is used. So unless you are doing something unusual with the Guice SPI, it applies to all bindings that form a part of the same `Injector`.

Best practice is to only have a single `Injector` per application, so `Binder` options are already effectively global.

For what it's worth, I think `requireExplicitBindings()` is overkill. Something like `requireAtInjectOnConstructors()` resolves the most egregious problems with implicit bindings, while still allowing for JSR-330 dependency injection based on annotated constructors, which can be a very convenient feature.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Pryden for the answer!